# Why is client-side locking not generally recommended?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

Please explain the following statement about synchronized blocks from "Core Java" by Hortsmann, Cornell (9 ed., p.865):

> The get and set methods of the Vector class are synchronized, but that doesn't help us.
>   ...
>   However, we can hijack the lock:
>
> ```
> public void transfer(Vector<Double> accounts, int from, int to, int amount)
> {
>     synchronized (accounts)
>     {
>         accounts.set(from, accounts.get(from) - amount);
>         accounts.set(to, accounts.get(to) + amount);
>     }
>     //...
> }
> ```
>
> This approach works, but it is entirely dependent on the fact that the Vector class uses the intrinsic lock for all of its mutator methods.

Why does the synchronization depend on the mentioned fact? If a Thread A 
owns the lock on accounts, no other Thread can acquire the same lock. It does not depend on a lock which Vector uses for its mutator methods.

The only possible explanation I was able to think of is the following one. Let Thread A owns lock on accounts. If Vector uses another lock for its set/get, then Thread A must acquire an additional lock to proceed through set/get, and this is impossible for some reason (can a Thread hold 2 different locks at the same time?).

This explanation does not look plausible to me, but I don't have anything else. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If a Thread A owns the lock on accounts, no other Thread can acquire the same lock. It does not depend on a lock which Vector uses for its mutator methods.

But if the Vector used a completely unrelated lock for its own synchronization, then your lock object would be pretty meaningless. Code like that would not synchronize:

```
x.transfer(vector, 100, 100, 100);  // uses your lock

vector.add(100);   // uses Vector's own, unrelated lock
```

If all your code goes through your own methods (which use your lock), and no one accesses vector's methods directly, then you are fine. (But then you don't need to use Vector's built-in synchronization at all, and could use ArrayList).

**These locks only work if all relevant code paths use them. There is usually more than one method involved, and they need to properly "talk to eachother" using the same set of locks. It is up to the programmer to ensure that.**

> Let Thread A owns lock on accounts. If Vector uses another lock for its set/get, then Thread A must acquire an additional lock to proceed through set/get, and this is impossible for some reason (can a Thread hold 2 different locks at the same time?).

It is not impossible, Thread A can hold any number of locks. However, in the access pattern above, it is pointless for Thread A to hold that first lock, because Thread B won't even try to lock it when it only uses the built-in Vector lock.

Comment: so the example introduced right before this one (i.e. `synchronized (lock) {accounts[from] -= amount;accounts[to] += amount; }`) is not as safe as this one, right? The book didn't point that out, it's wording is 'programmers use the lock of an object to implement additional atomic operations'

Answer (score 2):

> This approach works, but it is entirely dependent on the fact that the Vector class uses the intrinsic lock for all of its mutator methods.

This is trying to explain that you are locking on `accounts` and `Vector` is locking on the same object.  This means that other threads making changes to the `accounts` `Vector` will be locked out and you won't have a race condition.

If you didn't share this lock then you will have a race condition because there are 4 operations going on inside that `synchronized` block:

1. Getting the current value of the from account
2. Setting the from account with the decremented value
3. Getting the value of the to account
4. Setting the to account with the incremented value

Since there is a lock, I assume that other threads are modifying the other accounts in the background.  If `Vector` hypothetically changed their internal locking strategy, other threads could make a change to the from or to accounts in the middle of this process and screw up the accounting.  For example, if the from account got incremented between #1 and #2, then this value would be overwritten because of the transfer.

It is extremely bad form to depend on the internal locking paradigm of a class like this.  It means that if `Vector` decided to change it's locking mechanism (yes, I know it won't), your code would then have a race condition.  More likely is that another programmer (or future you) decides to change `accounts` to be a different `Collection` which used a different locking mechanism, the code would break.  You should not rely on the internal behavior of a class unless it is specifically documented as such.

If you need to protect against such a race condition then you should perform a `synchronized` lock around ever access to the `Vector`.

Btw, you should not use `Vector` anymore.  If you need a synchronized list, use `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Double>);` or one of the new concurrent classes introduced in Java 5.

Comment: "if Vector decided to change it's locking mechanism" That's not possible though. How it synchronizes is clearly part of the API, and they won't break that.

Comment: Where in the Javadocs for `Vector` does it mention that you can rely upon all of the methods being synchronized.  Wouldn't `Vector` work the same if they switched it to using an internal `private final Object lock`?  I know they aren't going to change it but it is the pattern that I'm objecting to. @Thilo.

Comment: @Thilo Actually, further in the book they mention that Vector does not make such promise.

Comment: My bad. I thought the methods being synchronized are part of the public API. Anyway, I agree it is a bad pattern to depend on it, and another bad pattern to use these supposedly thread-safe container classes in the first place (thread-safety in a meaningful way can only be ensured client-side as your pattern shows).

Comment: @Gray " It means that if Vector decided to change it's locking mechanism (yes, I know it won't), your code would then have a race condition."  - actually, this is my question: how it would be a race condition?

Comment: @TT_ That one piece of code in isolation would be fine. But not if someone also used the vector directly. See my answer for an example.

Comment: I've added more details as to the race condition @TT_.

Comment: @Gray So you mean another thread can do something outside this piece of code. That's what I was missing when asked the question. Now I realized the meaning of "supposedly thread-safe container class" remark above. Thanks, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I've not read the book, but what I think they want to say is that each `Vector` method is synchronized (independently) and even if this protects the `Vector` from corruption, it does not protect the information it could be stored in it (especially because of business rules, data models, data structure design, or however you want to call them).

Example:  Method `transfer` is implemented naïvely, trusting that if it `Vector`'s `set` method is synchronized, then everything is good.

```
public void transfer(Vector<Double> accounts, int from, int to, int amount) {
    accounts.set(from, accounts.get(from) - amount);
    accounts.set(to, accounts.get(to) + amount);
}
```

What could happen if 2 threads (T2, and T3) call `transfer` at the same time with, say, the same `from` account (A1) with balance $1,500 and different `to` accounts (A2, and A3) with balance $0?  Say $100 to A2 and $1,200 to A3?

1. T2:  `accounts.get('A1')` is retrieved and 100 is subtracted.  Result= 1,400, but it's **not stored back yet**.
2. T3:  `accounts.get('A1')` is retrieved (still 1,500) and 1,200 is subtracted.  Result= 300
3. T3:  Stores the result back:  `accounts.get('A1')` (if executed) would produce 300.
4. T2:  Stores the result previously computed.  If executed, `accounts.get('A1')` would produce 1,400.
5. T2:  `accounts.get('A2')` is retrieved (value 0), 100 added, and stored back.  `accounts.get('A2')` (if executed) would produce 100.
6. T3:  `accounts.get('A3')` is retrieved (value 0), 1,200 added, and stored back.  `accounts.get('A3')` (if executed) would produce 1,200.

So, we started with `A1` + `A2` + `A3` = 1,500 + 0 + 0 = 1,500, and after doing these internals transfers we have `A1` + `A2` + `A3` = 1,400 + 100 + 1,200 = 2,700.  Obviously something didn't work here.  What?  That between steps 1. and 4. T2 was keeping `A1`'s balance and did not (could not) detect that `T3` was also reducing it, at least at a conceptual level.

This is not going to happen with every run, of course.  But this is evil in disguise, as reproducing (and also finding and re-testing) the issue will be difficult if hidden in, say, a few dozen thousand lines of code.

However, note that the above happened even if `accounts` methods were never called simultaneously.  Not even an attempt.  In fact, `accounts` is not corrupted as a `Vector`, but it is corrupted as our data structure.

This is what the phrase

> The get and set methods of the Vector class are synchronized, but that doesn't help us.

refers to.

To say respect to the proposed solution that

> This approach works, but it is entirely dependent on the fact that the Vector class uses the intrinsic lock for all of its mutator methods.

, the authors surely assumed that besides the transfer method there also are other uses of `account`.  Example: add accounts, delete accounts, etc.  It's in this sense that it's fortunate those methods also synchronize on the vector.  Had them synchronized in an internal object, the developers of the system would have needed to wrap `accounts` in a secondary synchronization layer based, this time, in `accounts` itself or any other common object.

Finally, regarding

> If a Thread A owns the lock on accounts, no other Thread can acquire the same lock. It does not depend on a lock which Vector uses for its mutator methods.

That could be precisely the point:  all classes needing mutually exclusive access to a data structure need to agree on what object they are going to `synchronize`.  This case was extremely simple.  In more complex cases, the selection of this object is not trivial.  In many cases, instead if privileging one object over others, a special "locking" object is created.  But this has a limitation:  the whole data structure can be updated only once at a time.  In applications where this is a problem, more elaborate locking strategies need to be defined, and developers can have difficulty determining what objects could be locked, and which they should lock in each possible circumstance.  These strategies also need to pay attention to the possibility of deadlock and race conditions.